# Maven Spring project: Adding a custom library using Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I created the maven-spring project using the m2e plugin of eclipse. The project is working fine.

Now I want to add a custom library in that Maven-Spring project (using Eclipse IDE without writing any commands in the command prompt). I want to add the custom library in my project using the Eclipse IDE only.

Please advise?

Comment: What is your maven-spring project? What do you mean by "add a custom library". Do you have a custom library already? Or do you want to create a new one?

Comment: I am already having a custom library in my local drive and I want to add the same in my maven dependency. Can you please let me know how to add that custom library in my maven repository?

Comment: No need for an answer -- the question can be marked as a duplicate after getting five votes and the question will close.  @user182944 you can cast a vote of your own because this is your question.